# Flexbox in flexbox not working with ellipsis text overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In my testing (and as answered by my other SO questions), flexbox works well with overflowing text when it's consuming the full width of the page or having a fixed width parent element.
However, if a flexbox with dynamic width is within another dynamic width flexbox, it doesn't support `overflow: hidden` (and thus text-overflow) correctly and always uses the maximum width of its contents. Is there a way to fix this without setting a specific width on the parent element? Here's a full example:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.aside {
  flex: 0 0 220px;
  background: black;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*width: calc(100% - 220px)*/
}

.toolbar {
  display: flex;
  background: #eeeeee;
  height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<!-- Works -->
<div class="main">
  <div class="toolbar">
    <div class="title">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Doesn't work without setting width of .main -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="aside">
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="toolbar">
      <div class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a codepen with the above code to play around with the HTML/CSS:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xyNoeq

Comment: Add `overflow: hidden` to `.main` ? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LgKyvY

Comment: overflow: hidden to .main also works as per @sol comment

Comment: Thanks, the `overflow: hidden` option worked perfectly

Answer (score 3):

use `display:inline-grid` instead of `display:flex` to class **.toolbar**  as shown below:

```
.toolbar {
    display: inline-grid;
}
```

Here's the updated snippet:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.aside {
  flex: 0 0 220px;
  background: black;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*width: calc(100% - 220px)*/
}

.toolbar {
  display: inline-grid;
  background: #eeeeee;
  height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<!-- Works -->
<div class="main">
  <div class="toolbar">
    <div class="title">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Doesn't work without setting width of .main -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="aside">
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="toolbar">
      <div class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Most welcome @JDoe please accept this answer if it works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Make the calculation of the width of your `.main` element more specific. Only when it is inside the `.container` element. I just added a few lines of CSS.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.aside {
  flex: 0 0 220px;
  background: black;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* Added */
.container .main {
  width: calc(100% - 220px);
}

.toolbar {
  display: flex;
  background: #eeeeee;
  height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<!-- Works -->
<div class="main">
  <div class="toolbar">
    <div class="title">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Doesn't work without setting width of .main -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="aside">
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="toolbar">
      <div class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was just an example, the aside element can also have a dynamic width, so this option wouldn't work well. The other answers work without setting a fixed width.